# Need clarification on a simplification step in a differentiation problem

Tags: calculus

We have:
$$(x-y)^2 = x+y-1$$

To solve, I added the derivative operator with respect to $x$ on both sides of the equation, which simplified to:

$$(2y-2x)\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx} = -2x + 2y + 1 + \frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx}$$

Here is where I am confused, to solve for $\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx}$ we subtract $\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx}$ from both sides, I thought the $\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx}$ would cancel out on both sides but really what happens is:

$$(2y-2x-1)\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx} = -2x + 2y + 1$$

So my question is, why didn't the $\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{dx}$ cancel out and instead became a factored $-1$?

Comment: What assumptions are you using?  Why do you think $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1\frac{dy}{dx}$, so when we subtract $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from each side of the equation, we obtain $-\frac{dy}{dx} = -1\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the left-hand side of the equation, which allows us to factor out a $-1$.  Details follow.

If we assume that $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$, differentiating both sides of the equation
$$(x - y)^2 = x + y - 1$$
implicitly with respect to $x$ yields
\begin{align*}
2(x - y) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x - y) & = 1 + \frac{dy}{dx} && \text{Chain Rule}\\
2(x - y)\left(1 - \frac{dy}{dx}\right) & = 1 + \frac{dy}{dx}\\
2(x - y) - 2(x - y)\frac{dy}{dx} & = 1 + \frac{dy}{dx}\\
2x - 2y - 2x\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y\frac{dy}{dx} & = 1 + \frac{dy}{dx}\\
-2x\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{dy}{dx} & = 1 - 2x + 2y\\ 
(-2x + 2y - 1)\frac{dy}{dx} & = 1 - 2x + 2y\\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{1 - 2x + 2y}{-2x + 2y - 1}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

When you differentiate both sides of $$ (x-y)^2 = x+y-1$$

You get $$(2y-2x)dy/dx = 1+ dy/dx $$

$$(2y-2x) = 1+ dy/dx \implies  dy/dx = \frac {1}{ 2y-2x-1}$$

Comment: You forgot to apply the Chain Rule on the LHS.